# Добавление параметров в компонент

Tags: vue.js

В main.js объявляю глобально компоненты:

```
    import VaсansyCard from './components/vaсansy-card/vaсansy-card.vue'
    import VacansyLabel from './components/vaсansy-card/vaсansy-card-label.vue'
    import VaсansyModal from './components/vaсansy-card/vaсansy-card-modal.vue'
    import VaсansyStatus from './components/vaсansy-card/vaсansy-card-status.vue'
    import VaсansyIcons from './components/vaсansy-card/vacansy-card-icons.vue'
    import VaсansySlideDown from './components/vaсansy-card/vacansy-slide-down.vue'


    Vue.component ("vacansy-card", VaсansyCard)
    Vue.component ("vacansy-card-label", VacansyLabel)
    Vue.component ("vacansy-card-modal", VaсansyModal)
    Vue.component ("vacansy-card-status", VaсansyStatus)
    Vue.component ("vacansy-card-icons", VaсansyIcons)
    Vue.component ("vacansy-slide-down", VaсansySlideDown)


    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: h => h(App)
    })
```

Потом в компоненте vacansy-card я собираю из остальных компонентов общий блок:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card-content vacansy-card p-0 d-flex flex-wrap w-100 vacansy-slide-down">
            <div class="w-100 p-0 mb-3 border-0">
            <div class="card bg-color-4 border-0 Ttest-1 ">
                <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div>
                        ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ЗАГОЛОВОК (<h5></h5) 
                    </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex mt-3">
                    <div>
                        <div class="flex-auto bg-color-3" style="width: 220px; height: 220px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mx-3 d-flex flex-column">
                        <button class="btn btn-8 mt-auto">Откликнуться</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex w-100">
                    <div class="mr-3 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 justify-content-between">
                        <vacansy-card-modal></vacansy-card-modal>
                        <div>
                            <vacansy-card-icons></vacansy-card-icons>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1">
                        <vacansy-card-status></vacansy-card-status>
                        <vacansy-card-label></vacansy-card-label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <vacansy-slide-down></vacansy-slide-down>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Вопрос: Как передать (и где именно передавать) через props параметры в компонент, чтобы, например, отрисовывать два идентичных блока, но с разными заголовками в шапке. И второй вопрос: можно ли как-то в параметрах передать не только html заголовок, но и вообще целый отдельный компонент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передаете заголовок в компоненту:

```
<my-component :title="'Заголовок'" />
```

Принимаете в компоненте и вставляете:

```
<template>
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['title'],
    }
</script>
```

Передать компоненту можно, точнее можно передать ее имя, и вставить потом ее так:

```
<component :is="'my-component'"></component>
```

Но будет сложнее передать вместе с самой компонентой ее свойства.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться